# Delete Chart Based On Location?

Tags: c#, excel

Is it possible to delete an Excel Chart based off the location of the chart in the workbook?  For example, I am currently using the code below to delete charts by their name.  But the snare I hit is sometimes the chart has a different name.  The only consistent thing is that they are in the same location.  Or could someone tweak my code to where it will delete based off location:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape shp in oXL.Sheets["Sheet 1"].Shapes)
if (shp.Type == MsoShapeType.msoChart)
{
    if (shp.Name == "Chart 233" || shp.Name == "Chart 111") { shp.Delete(); }
}
```

Comment: Shapes have a `TopLeftCell` property which returns the Cell under the top-left corner of the shape.  You can use that to determine where the shape is on the worksheet.  Or you can use the shapes `Top` and `Left` properties and compare them to the `Top` and `Left` of a cell where you expect the plot to be located.

Comment: Using Shape.TopLeftCell would give me the top left cell, but once that information is obtained how would I actually delete that shape based from the Shape.TopLeftCell value?

Comment: Shp.Delete still works once you've determined if it's the chart you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this - will delete a chart if its top-left corner lies within the range B4:D8

```
    //...
    using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using ios = System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    //...

    private void btnDeleteChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xl = GetExcel();
        if (xl == null) return;

        Excel.Workbook wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook;
        Excel.Worksheet sht = wb.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Range rSrch = sht.Range["B4:D8"];

        Excel.Range rShp;

        foreach (Excel.Shape shp in sht.Shapes)
        if (shp.Type ==  Office.MsoShapeType.msoChart)
        {
            rShp = shp.TopLeftCell;
            if(xl.Intersect(rShp,rSrch)!=null)shp.Delete();
        }
    }

    private Excel.Application GetExcel()
    {
        Excel.Application xl = 
          (Excel.Application)ios.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        if (xl == null) MessageBox.Show("No Excel !!");
        return xl; 
    }
```